# Code for viewing comment reply form

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to add_css when comment reply form is viewed (not new comment form) and there is an example code below. How could the line $comment->nid == $node->nid (presumed to be responsible for viewing comment reply form) be changed and adapted to a function?

```
function hook_??? (???) {
  if ($comment->nid == $node->nid) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/MY_MODULE.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? How are the nodes/comments being displayed on the page? Are they in views or something? Often which hook is best depends on the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use `YourThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables)` in **tempalte.php** file

Comment: I tried YourThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables) but it does not work. Notice: Undefined variable: comment ... Notice: Undefined variable: node ...  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ...

Comment: OK, I added some more information to the question.

Comment: @gladiatorhl2 We don't have a support forum here, we can't guide you through every step of implementing this feature, or help you debug your code step-by-step. It doesn't suit our Q+A format, we're looking for a specific, easily understandable question that can have a specific, objective answer. Please take the time to learn what you need to about the API, and when you have a _specific_ question, just ask that. Currently it's not possible to understand what you're trying to do, as I think there are basic Drupal development concepts you're not familiar with.

Comment: If I've got that wrong then accept my apologies, but obviously if I _have_ got that wrong, you'll be able to update your question to make it obvious what you need to know. Remember, no-one here has seen your site before. We don't have the background to understand what you need to do just from the very brief specification you've put in the question. The more time you take to ask a clear question, that's generic enough to be useful to future visitors, the quicker and better the responses you'll get.

Comment: There is a thread on Drupal.org [Add class to comment reply form](https://www.drupal.org/node/2103219) - wouldn't it be simpler to do just that, and then use this class in CSS? To have one CSS, with rules for both cases?

Comment: I read this thread but the solution is not quite good because the core must be changed. I cannot find a hook which could allow all objects of a comment and a node at the same time (if I understand right)

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments it's a bit of a guess what you are trying to achieve. And my answer is also a guess but it was too long to add as a comment :)

The code below would go in to template.php in your theme. So if comments are listed on a node and it happens that the page you are at is the some node id as the comment add some css file.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object('node'); 
  if($node && $variables['elements']['#comment']->nid == $node->nid) { 
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/css/MY.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that this code doesn't work because $variables['elements']['#node'] is not an equivalent of $comment->nid   and I tried $variables['elements']['#node']['#comment']->nid  with the same negative result.   I would like to add_css when  comment reply form is viewed (not new comment form).

Comment: That's why some more information about what your setup is and what you want to achieve will help people give better answers.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: @PontusNilsson It still doesn't work and there are no any errors. If I replace the line "if($node && $variables['elements']['#comment']->nid == $node->nid)" with "if ($comment->nid == $node->nid)" , it works but with a lot of errors like Notice: Undefined variable: comment ...

Comment: @PontusNilsson I noticed something strange. That the above code works but in reverse (new comment form is viewed). In the initial code comment reply form is viewed :)

Comment: @PontusNilsson I suppose that only one line can be changed a little bit and everything works quite good: if(!($node && $variables['elements']['#comment']->nid == $node->nid))   I have a small question. Why must $node be added in this condition "if(!($node ..."    ?